# Why ViewContext.RouteData.Values["X"] return key vlaue ? while I expect just the value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I expect in Razor the @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] return an integer , While it return `'Id=X'`.

for instance my controller like :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

And in Razor :

```
<input type="text" value='@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]' id="routeDataId" />
```

the result is a Textbox with the value of `'Id=X'`

Comment: it returns `Id=X`, where X is your `int` value?

Comment: Yes , I expect the textbox shows X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect in Razor the @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] return an
>   integer , While it return Id=X.

Returning `Id=X` by `RouteData.Values["id"]` is correct behaviour, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.values%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to get a value of that object, you could use:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()
```

So, your input should look like:

```
<input type="text" value='@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()' id="routeDataId" />
```

If this also won't work, you could do that trick:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
 {
     if(id.HasValue)
        TempData["id"] = id;
     else
        TempData["id"] = "empty value";

     return View();
 }
```

and then:

```
<input type="text" value='@TempData["id"]' id="routeDataId" />
```

Comment: Thanks , Unfortunately nothing happened RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() return 'Id=X' too

Answer (score 0):

You should change quotes from `'` to `"` like this:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString()" id="routeDataId" />
```